# Как запланировать удаление файла через cmd?

Tags: cmd, deletelater

Мне необходимо через cmd строку Windows запланировать удаление файла.

Пример (конечно же не работает): `del main.exe -5 sec`

Буду очень рад если поможете.

Comment: https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/schtasks.html

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю

Comment: 1) `del path\main.exe`. 2) Использовать встроенный планировщик Windows